# How to create a case in-sensitive TEqualityComparer for TDictionary?

Tags: delphi

I have a case using TDictionary:

```
var D: TDictionary<string, integer>;
begin
  D := TDictionary<string, integer>.Create(TCustomEqualityComparer.Create());
  try
    D.Add('One', 1);
    D.Add('Two', 2);
    D.Add('Three', 3);

    showmessage(inttostr(D.Items['One']));
    showmessage(inttostr(D.Items['TWO']));
  finally
    D.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Class TCustomEqualityComparer is copied from [Generics Defaults TEqualityComparer (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeSamples/en/Generics_Defaults_TEqualityComparer_%28Delphi%29) with minor modification on GetHashCode method:

```
TCustomEqualityComparer = class(TEqualityComparer<string>)
public
  function Equals(const Left, Right: string): Boolean; override;
  function GetHashCode(const Value: string): Integer; override;
end;

function TCustomEqualityComparer.Equals(const Left, Right: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := SameText(Left, Right);
end;

function TCustomEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(const Value: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := BobJenkinsHash(Value[1], Length(Value) * SizeOf(Value[1]), 0);
end;
```

I expect the TCustomEqualityComparer able to perform the case-insensitive matching for the key values.  For example:

```
D.Items['TWO']
```

However, I get a "Item not found" exception.  I am using Delphi 2010 Version 14.0.3513.24210.

Does anyone know how what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks.  I have changed TCustomEqualityComparer.GetHashCode and it works as you said:

```
function TCustomEqualityComparer.Equals(const Left, Right: string): Boolean;
begin
  {$IFDEF UNICODE }
    Result := (Left.ToUpper = Right.ToUpper);
  {$ELSE }
    Result := SameText(Left, Right);
  {$ENDIF }
end;

function TCustomEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(const Value: string): Integer;
var s: string;
begin
  s := {$IFDEF UNICODE } Value.ToUpper {$ELSE } UpperCase(Value) {$ENDIF };
  Result := BobJenkinsHash(s[1], Length(s) * SizeOf(s[1]), 0);
end;
```

Comment: UpperCase/SameText only works for ASCII text (it only handles 'a'..'z'). Use .ToUpper in UNICODE versions of Delphi. Code snippet updated...

Answer (score 21):

```
uses System.Generics.Collections, System.Generics.Defaults;

var
  D: TDictionary<string, Integer>;
begin
  D := TDictionary<string, Integer>.Create(TIStringComparer.Ordinal); // ‹- this is the trick
  try
    D.Add('One', 1);
    .
    .
  finally
    D.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I know that this is an old answer, but I think it provides the opposite to the question. According to help file for System.Generics.Defaults.TIStringComparer.Ordinal, it "Returns a TStringComparer object that performs a case-sensitive string comparison.", not a case insensitive one.

Comment: @AdamG - This must be a mistake in the documentation, I just tested it out and it makes a case-insensitive comparison. That would also explain the I in the class name for InsensitiveStringComparer.

Answer (score 3):

The HashCode has to be the same for all values that return Equals = true! Try making Value uppercase in the GetHashCode before sending it to your HashFunction.

Comment: Are you sure the original Equals is already case-insensitive?

This is the original Equals method defined in unit Generics.Defaults.pas:

    function Equals_UString(Inst: PSimpleInstance; const Left, Right: UnicodeString): Boolean;
    begin
      Result := Left = Right;
    end;

Comment: You are right! I mixed up the original implementation and an example.